# ntpd not running

Tags: ntpd

- Have confirmed correct server is configured in `/etc/ntp.conf`
- It can ping that server.
- It definitely has the ntp package

  `/home/admin# dpkg -s ntp
  Package: ntp
  Status: install ok installed`
- But the daemon is not running

  `/home/admin# ps wax | grep ntp
  21959 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep ntp`
- Status check

  `/home/admin# ntpstat
  Unable to talk to NTP daemon. Is it running?`
- I get this when I try to restart it

  `/home/admin# systemctl start ntpd
  Failed to start ntpd.service: Unit ntpd.service failed to load: No such file or directory.`

What should try next?

Comment: You should reinstall ntp and check the dependencies etc., then check if there's a systemd unit present.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To check the status of `ntp` you should use:

```
systemctl status ntp
```

By modifying the `/etc/ntp.conf` you should restart the service through:

```
systemctl restart ntp
```

The `ntpstat` report `Unable to talk to NTP daemon. Is it running?` , you can simply start the `ntp` service through:

```
systemctl start ntp
```

To start the service at boot time:

```
systemctl enable ntp
```

Answer (score 0):

On my opensuse tumbleweed system, I get

```
systemctl start ntp
Unit ntp.service could not be found.
```

I replaced ntp with ntpd, and everything worked.

```
systemctl start ntpd
systemctl enabled ntpd
```